# Insert query inside a modal

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to ask for some assistance when it comes to inserting details into mysql database if data are inside a modal. I have been trying to complete this sample project of mine hoping that I can use it as a portfolio in the future. Here's the modal code.

main.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registrationModalold" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--<form action="functions/actions.php" method="POST">-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Enrollment Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="functions/actions.php">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Personal Information</h4>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">Name:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="courses">
            <?php 
              include 'ini/db.php'; //connect to database
              $sql = "SELECT distinct student_name FROM tbl_students";
              $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
              echo "<option>---SELECT STUDENT---</option>";

              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                echo "<option value=Course".$row['student_name'].">" . $row['student_name'] . "</option>";
              }
            ?>
            </select>
          </div><!-- ./col -->
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">Addres:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
          </div><!-- ./col -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">Contact:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
          </div><!-- ./col -->
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">BirthDate:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
          </div><!-- ./col -->
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">Birth Place:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
          </div><!-- ./col -->
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">Gender:</label>
            <select class="form-control">
              <option id="male">Male</option>
                <option id="female">Female</option>
            </select>
          </div><!-- ./col -->
        </div>
        </br></br>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Other Information</h4>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
              <label for="usr">Course:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="courses">
                <?php 
                  include 'ini/db.php'; //connect to database
                  $sql = "SELECT crs_id,crs_name FROM tbl_courses";
                  $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                  echo "<option>---SELECT COURSE---</option>";

                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<option value=Course".$row['crs_id'].">" . $row['crs_name'] . "</option>";
                  }
                ?>
                </select>
              </div><!-- ./col -->
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                <label for="usr">Major:&nbsp<font color="red" size="2"><i>optional</i></font></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
              </div><!-- ./col -->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <label for="usr">Mother's Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
              </div><!-- ./col -->
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <label for="usr">Mother's Occupation:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
              </div><!-- ./col -->
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <label for="usr">Father's Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
              </div><!-- ./col -->
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <label for="usr">Father's Occupation:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">
              </div><!-- ./col -->
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button name="btnregister" action="functions/actions.php" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there's a button there a button which points to my actions.php which is inside another folder which is functions folder. But when I click that nothing happens.

Here's the `action.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnregisters'])) {
    echo "ASASASASASASASASASASAS";
    die("asdsadsada");
}
```

Comment: `<label for="usr">Father's Name:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname">` — The `id` of the input needs to match the `for` attribute of the label that is associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see there's a button there a button which points to my actions.php which is inside another folder which is functions folder. But when I click that nothing happens
>
> ```
> <button name="btnregister" action="functions/actions.php" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
> ```

You said `type="button"`. The entire point of that is to make the button do nothing (so you can bind JavaScript event handlers to it).

Take that out and let it be the default (`type="submit"`) which would submit the form.

Comment: Silly me. Small problems are hard to find. So Sorry and Thank you for the help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please see that the submit button is set as button type = "button"

```
 <button name="btnregister" action="functions/actions.php" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

**Change it to:**

```
<button name="btnregister" action="functions/actions.php" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined action attribute in form tag. action attributes are not for buttons so do not write it there.

To submit a form you need a submit button so, change type of your save button from "button" to "submit"
it should be like

```
<button name="btnregister" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```